# Magento - Products ordered add sku - Report

Tags: magento, sku

I want to add the SKU to the report list and i found a solution on Google but i seem to have some problems with it.

What i did is that i added the following code to the Grid. It shows the sku for all simple products but not for all the configurable products. I want to show the SKU for the configurable products aswell just for the parent product.

Code added:

```
$this->addColumn('sku', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('SKU'),
        'width'     =>'50px',
        'index'     =>'sku'
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes adding this code will give us SKU but it will not show configurable product SKU

`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Report/Product/Sold/Grid.php`

In `protected function _prepareColumns()`

```
$this->addColumn('sku', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('reports')->__('Product Sku'),
            'index'     =>'sku'
        ));
```

For your solution go to

`app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php`

In `public function addOrderedQty($from = '', $to = '')`

find `->where('parent_item_id IS NULL')`
and change it to `->where('e.type_id = ?', 'simple')`

Please rewrite files if you need i have just tested this on core/Mage. 
It's tested in Magento ver. 1.9.3.0.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Problem is that i dont wont the simple products. I want statistics of the simple which isnt a child and then i want statistics of configurable (only parents, no childs). I dont care which size sold but only which products :) Hope you understand.

Comment: No one ever wanted this? I want SKU on configurable and simple (without parent).

Hope anything else can help me against a solution.

Comment: As standard its "->where('parent_item_id IS NULL')", but it still show the parrent name and not the name of the simple? But the sku is of a simple product.